# How to turn off cell data match highlighting in RIDE?

Tags: robotframework

Whenever I click a cell in the Robot Framework editor RIDE, it hangs/sticks for a while looking for matching cells so that it can highlight those for me. How do I turn off this feature in Robot Framework? I find this feature  slowing  me down while  working with Robot. I checked the Tools>Preferences option but did not find anything useful there.

Version: RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on python 2.7.6